# Boost Variant: Is there magic in the binding order?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I have been reading everything I can find about [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html).  (I have a headache.) Some people were surprised that assigning a string literal got saved as a bool.  If I listed `char*` before `bool` (after?) would a string literal get saved as a `char*` string?  Does the ordering between `v1` and `v2` matter here?

```
boost::variant<char*, bool> v1 = "hello";
boost::variant<bool, char*> v2 = "hello";
```

For integers, should I simply bind the largest integer for all integers or should I individually bind `int8_t` thru `int64_t`?  If I have them all bound then input one, which would fit in any of them, does it get saved as the first (last?) one?

How about `float` vs `double`?

Comment: "should I bind the largest integer" - depends on whether you need to preserve the type. I usually use "largest-int" approach, but it may not be good for your application

Comment: @odedsh what did you mean "for a string literal use `std::string`?".

Comment: @sehe: I meant that using a char* in a variant will probably not serve the intended purpose. An actual string won't be copied with the variant and without careful memory management OP will most probably end up with a segmentation fault.

I understand that this is not directly related to the question of the OP which is why I just wrote it in a comment

Comment: @odedsh Makes sense. Indeed, there's nothing specific or different about this when using (or not using) variants. Still don't see what "for a string literal use `std::string`" was supposed to recommend there. A string literal exists in code and is a `char const(&)[N]`. In fact, that's about the only type of char* that you _can_ rely on to exist throughout the lifetime of the program...

Comment: Deleting the comment I guess it is too unclear

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic.

There's just the documented behaviour of the constructor.

> `template<typename T> variant(T & operand);`
>
> **Requires**: T must be unambiguously convertible to one of the bounded types (i.e., T1, T2, etc.).
>
> **Postconditions**:   Content of *this is the best conversion of operand to one of the bounded types, as determined by standard overload resolution rules.
>
> **Throws**:   May fail with any exceptions arising from the conversion of operand to one of the bounded types.

Because both cases involve implicit conversions, it can happen that an unexpected element type is constructed.

See the below example

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d705d2381b9424d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main() {
    {
        boost::variant<bool, std::string> v;
        v = "hello"; // is char const(&)[6], converts to bool

        assert(0 == v.which());

        v = static_cast<char const*>("hello");
        assert(0 == v.which());
    }

    // compare to
    {
        boost::variant<bool, char const*> v;
        v = "hello"; // is char const(&)[6]

        assert(1 == v.which()); // now selects the direct match

        v = static_cast<char const*>("hello");
        assert(1 == v.which());
    }
}
```

Comment: Added a more friendly example showing how subtly things interact (_[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d705d2381b9424d)_)